# simple questions on circuitkz

Tags: circuitikz

I am a rather newbie to tikz, and in particular to `circuitikz` which is the package I am interested in at the moment. I've just created a simple circuit diagram with an operating amplifier, though I do not manage to do a couple of things I think are needed to have a nice final diagram.

[image: circuit]

In particular, I'd like to ask for your help to:

1. avoid the gap between the filled dot at the output and the upper line
2. be able to align the gnd symbols at the bottom of the figure

If you have any other advices on how to make my latex code simpler, nicer, or in summary just better, I would be very thankful to know about them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (oa) {};
\node (o) [right=0.5 of oa.out] {};
\draw (oa.-) |- (-1,2) -| (o) node[right] {$V_{\rm{out}}$};
\draw (oa.out) to[short] (o) to[R, l=$R_L$, *-] ++(0,-2) node[ground] {} ++(0,-2);
\draw (oa.+) to[short] ++(-0.5,0) to[sV, l=$1\,\rm{V}$] node[ground] {} ++(0,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And for some reason my original "Dear all" was not included... so apologies and greetings to the community

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! (It could be that because on stack-exchange sites one normally does neither include a greeting nor a thank you, your greeting was cut automatically).

Comment: Your MWE gives me: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/vco' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: Uhm.. ok, I've just replaced that component with 'sV'. May you please try again ?

Comment: Nice. Did not find your symbol, just saw it was not `VCo`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! We truly appreciate you took the time to add to your question a proper MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

[image]

1. Use a `\coordinate` instead of a `\node`; the gap in your code comes from the `inner sep`/`outer sep` associated to nodes.
2. Naming the `ground` node to the right, you can then use the perpendicular coordinate system to place the `ground` node to the left so both are vertically aligned.

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw 
  (0,0) node[op amp] (oa) {}
  coordinate[right=0.5 of oa.out] (o)
  (oa.-) |- (-1,2) -| (o) node[right] {$V_{\rm{out}}$}
  (oa.out) to[short] 
  (o) to[R, l=$R_L$, *-] 
  ++(0,-3) node[ground] (groundr) {}; 
\draw
  (oa.+|-groundr) node[ground] {}
  to[vco, l=$1\,\rm{V}$]  (oa.+);  
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As a side note, to properly typeset your units, I'd suggest you to use the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package loaded through the `siunitx` package option for `circuitikz` (thanks to **Paul Gessler** for [`this tip`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261057/simple-questions-on-circuitkz/261062?noredirect=1#comment625715_261062)):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw 
  (0,0) node[op amp] (oa) {}
  coordinate[right=0.5 of oa.out] (o)
  (oa.-) |- (-1,2) -| (o) node[right] {$V_{\rm{out}}$}
  (oa.out) to[short] 
  (o) to[R, l=$R_L$, *-] 
  ++(0,-3) node[ground] (groundr) {}; 
\draw
  (oa.+|-groundr) node[ground] {}
  to[vco, l=1<\volt>]  (oa.+);  
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not only does he have a nicer solution than me, but also 2 mins earlier :) (Not to mention that when I wrote *someone* in my answer, I was tempted to put your name there....)

Comment: Thanks a lot Gonzalo, impressive. Though, for the second point, I do not fully understand the logic behind... With the expression <pre><code>(oa.+|-groundr)</code></pre> you achieve the 'vertical alignment', but what coordinate is that one ? Also if I may, how could I shift horizontally the gnd + source line going to the positive input ? Also thanks for the tip on the units.

Comment: @Sergio You're welcome. `(coord1|-coord2)` means to take the x-coordinate of `coord1` and the the y-coordinate of `coord2`; for example, `(2,4|- 1,5)` will result in `(2,5)`. Regarding the horizontal shifting, could you please explain in more detail which line would you like to move? (I know nothing about circuits).

Comment: Gonzalo, `circuitikz` can use `siunitx` natively: load it with option `siunitx` and then you can do `l=1<\volt>`, etc.

Comment: @PaulGessler Ah, nice! I incorporated this to my solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Gonzalo, my apologies for being so unclear :-) I meant doing something like replacing your last draw command with: `\draw (oa.+) to[short] ++(-1,0) coordinate(b);
\draw (b|-groundr) node[ground] {} to[vco, l=\SI{1}{\V}] (b);
\end{circuitikz}`. Do not know if there's a better way. Thanks

Comment: @Sergio I see. you can avoid the extra coordinate using `\draw 
  ([xshift=-1cm]{oa.+|-groundr}) node[ground] {} to[vco, l=\SI{1}{\V}] ([xshift=-1cm]oa.+) -- (oa.+);`

Answer (score 1):

I adapted it to this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (oa) {};
\node (o) [right=0.5 of oa.out] {};
\draw (oa.-) |- (-1,2) -| ($(o) +(0,-2pt)$) node[right] {$V_{\rm{out}}$};
\draw (oa.out) to[short] (o) to[R, l=$R_L$, *-] ++(0,-2.2) node[ground] {} ++(0,-2);
\draw (oa.+) to[short] ++(-0.5,0) to[sV, l=$1\,\rm{V}$] node[ground] {} ++(0,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that you now need the `calc` library. It is basically some manual fine-tuning. Maybe someone will have a better solution that adapts to future changes of positions.

There are ways, for example using the `let` syntax, to achieve this. But if it is just for one single and small diagram, I think that's not necessary.

Comment: Got the point here with the vertical negative shift, thanks !